# onChanged is never called when getting data from Firebase using LiveData

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have the following activity class:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        splashViewModel.nameLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String name) {
                Log.d(TAG, name); //Isn't printing anything
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my view model class:

```
public class SplashViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private SplashRepository repository;
    MutableLiveData<String> nameLiveData;

    @Inject
    SplashViewModel(SplashRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
        nameLiveData = repository.addNameToLiveData();
    }
}
```

This is my repository class:

```
class SplashRepository {
    MutableLiveData<String> addNameToLiveData() {
        MutableLiveData<String> nameMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        ref.document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if(document.exists()) {
                    String name = document.getString("name");
                    Log.d(TAG, name); //Is printed out correctly
                    nameMutableLiveData.postValue(name);
                }
            }
        });
        return nameMutableLiveData;
    }
}
```

I'm using `postValue()` to add data to the `LiveData`. In the callback it is printing the name correctly but when observing the `nameLiveData` object, the `onChanged` is not even triggered. How to solve this?

Comment: You need to either observe `nameMutableLiveData` on your ViewModel or return the value of the String name using an onCompletion interface.    
You're returning the LiveData before getting the response of Firebase, it's an async call, so there is no point of posting value there.

Comment: @Shermano Isn't this what I'm doing, observing the `nameMutableLiveData` object using `splashViewModel.nameLiveData.observe(...)`? Second, I'm posting the value in the callback as soon it is available. Is there any other way?

Comment: I have a feeling that it not works this way, you should using MeaditorLiveData instead, but Im not so sure, maybe someone can help you better, cheers

Comment: You say I should use `MediatorLiveData` instead of `MutableLiveData`? Just did and have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Repos should have non mutable and mutable live data objects.Repo should expose non mutable live data object which will be observed in view model using observeforever method .
The non mutable objects gets updated with mutable object.
Sample app example

https://github.com/ashok07m/Pokemon-Sample-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/learning/pokemon/data/repository/MainRepositoryImpl.kt

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still confused. How should I do what you say?

Comment: See the example link